# Firebase Cloud Functions wait until asynchronous data is received from database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to check if a data exists in Firebase Realtime DB. The problem is that B is always executed since when `if(snapshot.exists())` is executed, it does not have the true value, because it is an asynchronous call, so it has no value.

```
  ref.child("Users").child(theDataToAdd).once('value', function(snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.exists()) {
           //A
      }else{
          //B
      }

  });
```

How can I achieve to wait until the if statement gets a true/false value and then continue the execution of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the callback argument argument of once.  Use the returned promise instead, and keep using promises.

```
ref.child("Users").child(theDataToAdd).once('value').then(snapshot => {
    // do the next thing here
})
```

If you don't know how promises work, watch this video series starting here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&index=1&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM

It's difficult to be effective with Cloud Functions without fully understanding promises.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am getting " Each then() should return a value or throw" error.

Comment: You're going to have to take some time to learn promises, or we'll go back and forth on this forever.